# How does C++ pick which overloaded function to call?

Tags: c++, inheritance, programming-languages, function, multiple-inheritance

Say I have three classes:

```
class X{};
class Y{};
class Both : public X, public Y {};
```

I mean to say I have two classes, and then a third class which extends both (multiple-inheritance).

Now say I have a function defined in another class:

```
void doIt(X *arg) { }
void doIt(Y *arg) { }
```

and I call this function with an instance of both:

```
doIt(new Both());
```

This causes a compile-time error, stating that the function call is ambiguous.

What are the cases, besides this one, where the C++ compiler decides the call is ambiguous  and throws an error, if any? How does the compiler determine what these cases are?

Comment: yes but i didnt have access to a C++ compiler

Comment: http://codepad.org/ for gcc and http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/ for comeau are two good sites for quick testing.

Comment: ah, codepad is what i was looking for, thanks! i was also looking for an explanation on the topic, not just "how does this work if i run it"

Comment: @Claudiu, I added links to the source material for my answer.

Comment: Had a similar issue with doIt(string a) and doIt(char *a). It's not a question of "just try it out". Even with a "char *" it will call into doIt(string a), so this is a valid question. Came across this because i was calling into a function using a string type, which in turn called a char * version of teh function. However the string input function was recursing indefinitely until it blew up the stack.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple: if it's ambiguous, then the compiler gives you an error, forcing you to choose.  In your snippet, you'll get a different error, because the type of `new Both()` is a pointer to `Both`, whereas both overloads of `doIt()` accept their parameters by value (i.e. they do not accept pointers).  If you changed `doIt()` to take arguments of types `X*` and `Y*` respectively, the compiler would give you an error about the ambiguous function call.

If you want to explicitly call one or the other, you cast the arguments appropriately:

```
void doIt(X *arg) { }
void doIt(Y *arg) { }
Both *both = new Both;
doIt((X*)both);  // calls doIt(X*)
doIt((Y*)both);  // calls doIt(Y*)
delete both;
```

Comment: +1 despite the use of C style cast (and manual memory management)

Answer (score 5):

I get this error with gcc:

```
jeremy@jeremy-desktop:~/Desktop$ g++ -o test test.cpp
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:18: error: call of overloaded ‘doIt(Both&)’ is ambiguous
test.cpp:7: note: candidates are: void doIt(X)
test.cpp:11: note:                 void doIt(Y)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfect example of using `boost::implicit_cast`:

```
void doIt(X *arg) { }
void doIt(Y *arg) { }

doIt(boost::implicit_cast<X*>(new Both));
```

Unlike with other solutions (including static_cast), the cast will fail if no implicit conversion from `Both*` to `X*` is possible. This is done by a trick, best shown at a simple example:

```
X * implicit_conversion(X *b) { return b; }
```

That's what is `boost::implicit_cast`, just that it is a template which tells it the type of `b`.

Comment: @litb can you explain what is the difference between static_cast and implcit_cast

Comment: you can down-cast with static_cast. not so with implicit_cast. static_cast basically allows you to do any implicit conversion, and in addition the reverse of any implicit conversion (up to some limits. you can't downcast if there is a virtual base-class involved). But implicit_cast will *only* accept implicit conversions. no down-cast, no void*->T*, no U->T if T has only explicit constructors for U.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler does a depth-search, not a breadth-search for picking overloads.
The full answer is in [Herb Sutter's exceptional C++](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/xc++.htm), unfortunately I don't have the book in hand.

Edit: Got the book at hand now
It's called the depth first rule is called ["The Interface Principle"](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill02.htm):

> The Interface Principle For a class X,
>   all functions, including free
>   functions, that both    (a) "mention"
>   X, and    (b) are "supplied with" X
>   are logically part of X, because they
>   form part of the interface of X.

but there is a secondary rule called the ["Koenig Lookup"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_dependent_name_lookup), that makes things harder.

> Quote:"(simplified): if you supply a
>   function argument of class type (here
>   x, of type A::X), then to look up the
>   correct function name the compiler
>   considers matching names in the
>   namespace (here A) containing the
>   argument's type" *-Herb Sutter,
>   Exceptional C++, p120*

Answer (score 1):

you need to explicitly cast your argument to either x or y

doIt(new Both());

so add...

(X *)   or   (Y *)

like...

doIt((X *)new Both());

Comment: You mean (X *) and (Y *), i'll fix that for you

Comment: Also, you should favor c++ style casts

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the C++ compiler will always pick the closest and most specific match that it can determine at compile time.

However, if your object is derived from both, I think that the compiler should give you an error or at least a very severe warning. Declaration order should not matter since this is about subtyping relations, and the first object is not "more of a subtype" than the other.