# const_cast vs static_cast

Tags: c++, casting, constants, implicit-conversion

To add `const` to a non-const object, which is the prefered method? `const_cast<T>` or `static_cast<T>`. In a recent question, someone mentioned that they prefer to use `static_cast`, but I would have thought that `const_cast` would make the intention of the code more clear. So what is the argument for using `static_cast` to make a variable const?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't use either.  Initialize a const reference that refers to the object:

```
T x;
const T& xref(x);

x.f();     // calls non-const overload
xref.f();  // calls const overload
```

Or, use an `implicit_cast` function template, like [the one provided in Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/boost/implicit_cast.hpp):

```
T x;

x.f();                           // calls non-const overload
implicit_cast<const T&>(x).f();  // calls const overload
```

Given the choice between `static_cast` and `const_cast`, `static_cast` is definitely preferable:  `const_cast` should only be used to *cast away* constness because it is the only cast that can do so, and casting away constness is inherently dangerous.  Modifying an object via a pointer or reference obtained by casting away constness may result in undefined behavior.

Comment: Most casts can be "dangerous".

Comment: Scott Meyers gives an example of using a `static_cast` to `const` followed by a `const_cast` to cause the non-`const` version of `operator[]` to call the `const` version. Can the same be achieved using a const reference?

Comment: It looks like you *can* replace the `static_cast` by instantiating a new const reference, but of course you must still use `const_cast` to return a non-const reference. I'm not sure if this is compiler- or platform-specific behavior, though, or if it's implied by any of the requirements in the standard.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say `static_cast` is preferable since it will only allow you to cast from non-`const` to `const` (which is safe), and not in the other direction (which is not necessarily safe).

Comment: This appears to match Scott Meyers' opinion; see _Effective C++_, Item 3, in the "Avoiding Duplication..." example.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good use case for an [implicit_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868306/what-is-the-difference-between-static-cast-and-implicit-cast/869597#869597) function template.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own cast:

```
template<class T>
const T & MakeConst(const T & inValue)
{
    return inValue;
}
```