# Using decltype to cast this to const

Tags: c++, constants, c++11, decltype

I'm attempting to solve a problem in which `decltype` will greatly simplify things, but I'm running into an issue using `decltype` on `*this` and adding a `const` qualifier. The sample code below demonstrates the problem.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
  void bar()
  {
    static_cast<const decltype(*this)&>(*this).bar();
  }

  void bar() const
  {
    std::cout << "bar" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Foo f;
  f.bar(); // calls non-const method
  return 0;
}
```

The code compiles in MSVC2010, but execution recurses until a stack overflow occurs.

[Ideone](http://www.ideone.com/VflMt) reports compiler error

```
prog.cpp: In member function 'void Foo::bar()':
prog.cpp:7:38: error: 'const' qualifiers cannot be applied to 'Foo&'
```

If I change the line

```
static_cast<const decltype(*this)&>(*this).bar();
```

to

```
static_cast<const Foo&>(*this).bar();
```

it works as expected.

Am I misusing or misunderstanding decltype?

Comment: `const_cast` may express the intent a bit better.

Comment: @Cubbi Express the intent to whom?

Comment: @Jesse : I presume he means `const_cast<Foo const*>(this)->bar();` is easier to _read_ than anything involving `decltype` for this scenario.

Comment: @ildjam I meant to suggest using const_cast to show that all that complicated expression does is alter constness, but [looks like I was wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402318/const-cast-vs-static-cast).

Comment: Note that the type of `*this` can always be specified by the injected-class-name, even inside a template. `decltype( *this )` could only be useful in a preprocessor macro.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - You caught me. ;) I am indeed using `decltype` in a preprocessor macro to "generate" some code for a certain idiom involving const correctness. I realize that the preprocessor is not the ideal code generation tool.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since the expression `*this` is not an *id-expression* (i.e. it doesn't name an entity, like a variable), then `decltype(*this)` gives the type of the expression `*this`. That type is `Foo&`, so adding a `const` qualifier and making a reference to that doesn't change anything: either it silently collapse to `Foo&` (following rules like reference collapsing), or it's an error (a const reference type). I'm not sure which behaviour is correct, and you have in fact found two compilers which behave differently. In any case it doesn't matter because it's not what you want.

You can use `std::remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::type const&` instead but that looks a bit ugly.

In case you're still confused:

```
int* p;
// decltype(p) is the type of the variable p (or, the declared type)
// int*

// decltype( (p) ) is the type of the expression p
// int*& because p is an lvalue

// decltype(*p) is the type of the expression *p
// int& because *p is an lvalue
```

Comment: `std::remove_reference` works well for me. Thanks for the advice!