# decltype(*this) bug in VS2013?

Tags: gcc, c++11, visual-studio-2013, decltype

While trying to formulate a C macro to ease the writing of non-const member functions calling const member functions with exact same logic (see Chapter 1, Item 3, "Avoiding Duplication in const and Non-const Member Functions" in [Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876)), I believe I came across a `decltype()` bug in VS2013 Update 1.

I wanted to use `decltype(*this)` to build a `static_cast<decltype(*this) const&>(*this)` expression in the aforementioned macro to avoid having the macro call site pass any explicit type information. However, that latter expression doesn't appear to properly add const in some cases in VS2013.

Here's a small block of code I was able to make repo the bug:

```
#include <stdio.h>

template<typename DatumT>
struct DynamicArray
{
    DatumT* elements;
    unsigned element_size;
    int count;

    inline const DatumT* operator [](int index) const
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= count)
            return nullptr;

        return &elements[index];
    }

    inline DatumT* operator [](int index)
    {
#if defined(MAKE_THIS_CODE_WORK)
        DynamicArray const& _this = static_cast<decltype(*this) const&>(*this);
        return const_cast<DatumT*>(_this[index]);
#else
        // warning C4717: 'DynamicArray<int>::operator[]' : recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow
        return const_cast<DatumT*>(
                static_cast<decltype(*this) const>(*this)
                [index]
            );
#endif
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DynamicArray<int> array = { new int[5], sizeof(int), 5 };
    printf_s("%d", *array[0]);
    delete array.elements;

    return 0;
}
```

(may the first one to blab about not using std::vector be smitten)

You can either compile the above code and see the warning yourself, or refer to my lone comment to see what VC++ would spew at you. You can then ! the `defined(MAKE_THIS_CODE_WORK)` expression to have VC++ compile the code as how I'm excepting the `#else` code to work.

I don't have my trusty clang setup on this machine, but I was able to use GCC Explorer to see if clang complains ([click to see/compile code](http://goo.gl/w997Hf)). Which it doesn't. However, g++ 4.8 will give you an `‘const’ qualifiers cannot be applied to ‘DynamicArray&’` error message using that same code. So perhaps g++ also has a bug?

Referring to the [decltype and auto](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1478.pdf) standards paper (albeit, it's almost 11 years old), the very bottom of page 6 says that `decltype(*this)` in a non-const member function should be `T&`, so I'm pretty sure this should be legal...

So am I wrong in trying to use decltype() on *this plus adding const to it? Or is this a bug in VS2013? And apparently g++ 4.8, but in a different manner.

**edit**: Thanks to Ben Voigt's response I was able to figure out how to craft a standalone C macro for what I'm desire to do.

```
// Cast [this] to a 'const this&' so that a const member function can be invoked
// [ret_type] is the return type of the member function. Usually there's a const return type, so we need to cast it to non-const too.
// [...] the code that represents the member function (or operator) call
#define CAST_THIS_NONCONST_MEMBER_FUNC(ret_type, ...)   \
    const_cast<ret_type>(                               \
        static_cast<                                    \
            std::add_reference<                         \
                std::add_const<                         \
                    std::remove_reference<              \
                        decltype(*this)                 \
                    >::type                             \
                >::type                                 \
            >::type                                     \
        >(*this)                                        \
        __VA_ARGS__                                     \
    )
// We can now implement that operator[] like so:
return CAST_THIS_NONCONST_MEMBER_FUNC(DatumT*, [index]);
```

The original desire was to hide this all in a macro, which is why I wasn't wanting to worry about creating typedefs or `this` aliases. It is still curious that clang in GCC Explorer didn't output a warning...though the output assembly does appear fishy.

Comment: I suppose my question could be considered a duplicate of this one (though I didn't come across it while researching my initial question) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416251/using-decltype-to-cast-this-to-const

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said yourself, `decltype (*this)` is `T&`.  `decltype (*this) const &` tries to form a reference to a reference (`T& const &`).  `decltype` triggers the reference collapsing rule 8.3.2p6.  But it doesn't collapse the way you'd like.

You could say `decltype(this) const&`, but that would be `T* const&` -- a reference to a const pointer, not a pointer to a const object.  For the same reason, `decltype (*this) const` and `const decltype (*this)` don't form `const T&`, but `(T&) const`.  And top-level `const` on a reference is useless, since references already forbid rebinding.

Perhaps you are looking for something more like

```
const typename remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::type &
```

But note that you don't need the cast at all when adding `const`.  Instead of

```
DynamicArray const& _this = static_cast<decltype(*this) const&>(*this);
```

just say

```
DynamicArray const& _this = *this;
```

These combine to

```
const typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::type & this_ = *this;
```

Still, this is a stupid amount of code for a very simple and pervasive problem.  Just say:

**`const auto& this_ = *this;`**

---

FYI here's the text of the reference collapsing rule:

> If a *typedef-name* (7.1.3, 14.1) or a *decltype-specifier* (7.1.6.2) denotes a type `TR` that is a reference to a type `T`, an attempt to create the type "lvalue reference to *cv* `TR`" creates the type "lvalue reference to `T`", while an attempt to create the type "rvalue reference to *cv* `TR`" creates the type `TR`.

`decltype(*this)` is our decltype-specifier which denotes `TR`, which is `DynamicArray<DatumT>&`.  Here, `T` is `DynamicArray<DatumT>`.  The attempt `TR const&` is the first case, attempt to create lvalue reference to (const) `TR`, and therefore the final result is `T&`, not `const T&`.  The cv-qualification is outside the innermost reference.

Comment: Thanks Ben! I updated my question with the C macro I was trying to create to hide this nonsense, along with avoiding typedef's or `this` aliases. I'm still curious as to why clang in GCC Explorer didn't raise an error or even a warning...will have to try it out in a proper environment when I get home.

Comment: @kornman00: Before I realized `auto` could be used, a previous version of this answer suggested `template<typename T> const T& deref_as_const(T* that) { return *that; }`  Use that instead of all this type-trait garbage.  Try to never use an explicit cast when an implicit conversion exists.  If you get the cast wrong... well, you've told the compiler to just shut up and do what it is told.

Comment: Where am I using an explicit cast? I could have sworn I stuck to static_cast (which is implicit) and const_cast (required, due to the const member function returning a const object) in all of the code I posted. And while I was trying to avoid exposing any details to the macro itself, that `de_ref_as_const` helper function is good too

Comment: Whoops, was thinking of implicit conversion. Either way, as I understand it `static_cast` should only perform legal conversions, where as a C cast tells the compiler to shut up.

Comment: @kornman00: `static_cast` is definitely safer than `reinterpret_cast` or C-style cast, but still silently performs casts which aren't wanted here, for example invocation of explicit constructors or down-casts.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to your macro

```
// Cast [this] to a 'const this&' so that a const member function can be invoked
// [ret_type] is the return type of the member function. Usually there's a const return type, so we need to cast it to non-const too.
// [...] the code that represents the member function (or operator) call
#define CAST_THIS_NONCONST_MEMBER_FUNC(ret_type, ...)   \
    const_cast<ret_type>(                               \
        static_cast<                                    \
            std::add_reference<                         \
                std::add_const<                         \
                    std::remove_reference<              \
                        decltype(*this)                 \
                    >::type                             \
                >::type                                 \
            >::type                                     \
        >(*this)                                        \
        __VA_ARGS__                                     \
    )
```

It's much cleaner to do

```
// Cast [this] to a 'const this&' so that a const member function can be invoked
template<typename T> const T& deref_as_const(T* that) { return *that; }

// [ret_type] is the return type of the member function. Usually there's a const return type, so we need to cast it to non-const too.
// [...] the code that represents the member function (or operator) call
#define CAST_THIS_NONCONST_MEMBER_FUNC(ret_type, ...)   \
    const_cast<ret_type>(deref_as_const(this)__VA_ARGS__)
```

It's shorter, self-contained, compatible with C++98 except for `__VA_ARGS__`, and avoids an unnecessary cast

Comment: Need to remove the dereference of `this` in the macro, but otherwise it works. Although, DEBUG builds will generate a function for deref_as_const for each type that instantiates it (the more verbose and code dense macro doesn't), even if you declare as `inline` (in VC++ at least).

Comment: Good catch on having two dereferences.