# How to use const qualifier with decltype?

Tags: c++, c++11

How do I use `const` qualifier with `decltype` for *template*-ed function ?

Current GCC [*rejects*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b24b9357c0dd1946) following :

```
template <typename It>
bool process(It first , It last )
{

  return  std::all_of( first, last, 
                       [](  const decltype(*first)& i )
                       //   ^^^^^ without const it works fine
                       { 
                            return i % 2 == 0; 
                       } 
                     ) ;
}
```

Is it legal/possible to use `i` as `const` reference inside the lambda ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416251/using-decltype-to-cast-this-to-const.

Comment: Looks like clang [accepts](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95c2db6ee60006f0) it with `const` qualifier

Comment: @P0W Not quite as intended: it effectively ignores the `const` and gives `i` type `int&`.

Comment: [For some reason I found that a simple helper alias resolves the error.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75ade888e8aa724a)

Answer (score 5):

`const decltype(*first)&` doesn't work because `decltype(*first)` is `int&`, but you expect it to be `int`. You can use `std::remove_reference` to work around that (although it doesn't really make the code clearer): `const std::remove_reference<decltype(*first)>::type&`

Answer (score 2):

Just resolve to std::iterator_traits:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <typename It>
bool process(It first , It last )
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type value_type;
    return std::all_of(first, last, []( const value_type& i ) {
        return i % 2 == 0;
    });
}

int main(void) {
    std::vector<int> v = { 0, 2, 4 };
    process(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```

Or without iterator_traits:

```
typedef typename std::decay<decltype(*first)>::type value_type;
```

Which leads to: A const qualifier is pointless for a reference and the `const decltype(*first)&)` is giving a false promise of having an immutable argument, which is actually mutable.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, this is the other way round, but it just happen that I ended up with that ugly way, and now I'm looking for _why_ that's failing

Answer (score 2):

You could [add_const](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e75ca9b7f93b63b) :

```
template <typename It>
bool process(It first , It last )
{
  // std::cout << "Typeid :" << typeid( const decltype(*begin) &).name( ) << '\n' ;

  return  std::all_of( first, last, 
                       [](  typename add_const<decltype(*first)>::type &i )
                       { //          ^^^^^^^^^               
                            return i % 2 == 0; 
                       } 
                     ) ;
}
```