# Using const_cast for creating non-const variant of methods

Tags: c++, methods, return, constants, const-cast

Can the const_cast be used for creating non-const versions of already implemented methods? I think I saw something along these lines (with recommendation for the const method to do the actual work), but I'm not really sure how it's supposed to work.

```
Value& const search(key) const {
    // find value with key
    return value;
}

Value& search(key) {
    return const_cast<Value&>(search(key));
}
```

If not this way, what is recommended way of creating non-const functions without code duplicity?

Comment: First of all, look up the word "duplicity."  It does not mean "duplication."  I'll wait....  Okay. Casting away const is something you usually do only when you find yourself in a bad predicament and up against a deadline. There are exceptions. For example, if a class has a cache that is transparent to the public. When const was introduced into the language, there was a debate as to whether "const" should mean really, really constant, or "as if" constant. "As if" won, and thus casting away const was born.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/123758/1896169

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is with `as_const` from C++17:

```
Value& search(key) {
    return const_cast<Value&>(std::as_const(*this).search(key));
}
```

Without it you can do this instead (or implement it yourself, it's not very hard)

```
Value& search(key) {
    return const_cast<Value&>(static_cast<const T&>(*this).search(key));
}
```

Where `T` is the type of your class (you can have a generic solution with `decltype` but it gets really ugly due to `decltype(*this)` being a reference type).

You can take a look at the `as_const` implementation [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const) or the generic cast [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416251/using-decltype-to-cast-this-to-const).

Comment: Are there any other ways to do it, compatible with C++14?

Comment: You can cast `this` to the correponding `const` pointer or define tour own version of `as_const()`, e.g., `template <typename T> T const& as_const(T const& x) { return x; }`. Personally I dislike casting `const` away and I’d rather implement a templaize algorithm potentially using `static` or `friend` functions and return its result in the `const`/non-`const` overloads.

Comment: We try to follow the coding rule "Avoid code duplication", but end up violating the rule "Avoid casting".

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches.

First:

```
namespace notstd{ // backported C++17
  template<class T>
  T const& as_const(T& t){return t;}
  template<class T>
  T const&& as_const(T&& t){return t;}      
}
namespace utility { // not ever in std
  template<class T>
  T& remove_const(T const& t){return const_cast<T&>(t);}
  template<class T>
  T&& remove_const(T const&& t){return const_cast<T&&>(t);}
}
```

then:

```
Value& const search(Key key) const {
  // find value with key
  return value;
}

Value& search(Key key) {
  return utility::remove_const(notstd::as_const(*this).search(key));
}
```

or alternatively:

```
Value& const search(Key key) const {
  return search(*this, key);
}

Value& search(Key key) {
  return search(*this, key);
}
private:
  template<class Self>
  friend decltype(auto) search(Self& self, Key key){
    // find value with key
  }
```

where we delegate the work to a friend template where `self` is maybe-const.