# Why does a const_cast (or static_cast) not add const?

Tags: c++, c++11, static-cast, const-cast

I was looking at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11127688) and wanted to use. However, I get a segmentation fault, when using the `static_cast` and `const_cast`, but if I use a temp variable everything is fine. It is obviously because the non-const version of `bar()` calls it self over-and-over. But I though the `static_cast` would result in a `const foo*` and then choose the const version of `bar()`. Why is that so?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class foo
{
    public:
    void bar() const
    {
        cout << "const" << endl;
    }

    void bar()
    {
        cout << "non-const" << endl;

//      static_cast<const decltype(this)>(this)->bar();

//      const_cast<const decltype(this)>(this)->bar();

        const auto& tmp = *this;
        tmp.bar();
    }
};

int main() {
    foo A;
    A.bar();
    const foo B;
    B.bar();
    static_cast<const foo*>(&A)->bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @songyuanyao, remove the commented lines. It will recurse forever

Comment: `this` is a pointer, so it has type `foo*`. When you add constness to `foo*`, you get `foo* const`, not `foo const*` as you might expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`decltype(this)` is `foo*`. And `const decltype(this)` is `foo* const`.

You don't change the pointees cv-qualifications, only the pointers. Therefore the non-const overload is chosen every time.

Comment: Ok, that actually make sense. I guess the same thing happens if I cast it to a reference, it would then be a `foo& const` (which is nonsense) instead of a `const foo&`.

Comment: Which also hints at what could be done instead, but could be useful to mention explicitly: `static_cast<const std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*this)>*>(this)` should work. It's long though, but it avoids what I think the OP tried to avoid: it avoids specifying the type explicitly.

Comment: @hvd, one can also use `static_cast<add_const_deep<decltype(this)>::type>(this)` where the meta-function is defined something like [this](http://ideone.com/RPGzLf). Haven't thoroughly tested though.

Comment: @StoryTeller your `add_const_deep` does not require C++14, which is nice for production code.

Comment: Yet another example of why "leading `const`" is misleading.  `const` applies to the part of the type on the left of where `const` is, except if you put it first, then where it applies depends on more complex rules than I can summarize in this comment, especially when you factor in aliases.  `decltype(this) const` is clear; `const decltype(this)` has the same meaning.  Meanwhile, if `this` is `X*`, then `X* const` and `const X*` have different meanings; the "leading `const`" changes behavior depending on if it leads an alias or not; the trailing *does not*.