# Is static_cast misused?

Tags: c++, casting, type-safety, static-cast

I have mixed feelings about `static_cast`, as it is the safest C++ cast available, but allows both safe and unsafe conversions at the same time, so you have to know the context to say if it is actually safe or might lead to UB (e.g. when casting to a sub-class).

So why isn't there a safer explicit cast? Here is an example, where it could be useful. In COM, they have to return the interface pointer as `void** ppv`, so "have to" cast explicitely

```
*ppv = (IInterface*) this;
```

which was then suggested to be replaced by a safer C++ cast

```
*ppv = static_cast<IInterface*>(this);
```

But does it make sense to make even a `static_cast` here? `this` is of a class which derives from `IInterface`, so one could simply write

```
IInterface* p = this; // implicit conversion to base, safe for sure
*ppv = p;
```

or use a helper like

```
template<class T, class U>
T implicit_cast(U p) { return p; }

*ppv = implicit_cast<IInterface*>(this);
```

So, is it true that `static_cast` is sometimes misused and can (should?) be replaced by this `implicit_cast` in some cases, or am I missing something?

EDIT: I know that [a cast is required in COM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742848/why-exactly-do-i-need-an-explicit-upcast-when-implementing-queryinterface-in-an), but it does not have to be `static_cast`, an implicit cast would be enough.

Comment: Note: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/869597 for the "right" implementation of `implicit_cast` (and a nice explanation).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this particular case I believe that it's always known that the casting will be upwards and that therefore `static_cast` should be perfectly safe.

It does appear that using your `implicit_cast` would probably be safer, and allows you to explicitly pick which base class you want to implicitly cast to (which is apparently required for COM).

I did a quick test with g++ and `implicit_cast` does indeed return different addresses for different base classes as expected.

Do note however that in regards to your very first sentence I would argue that `dynamic_cast` is in fact safer than `static_cast` since it will return null or throw if the cast can't be completed. In contrast, `static_cast` will return a valid-looking pointer and let you keep going until your program blows up at some time in the future, unconnected to the original bad cast.

Test program:

```
#include <iostream>

class B1
{
public:
    virtual ~B1() {}
};

class B2
{
public:
    virtual ~B2() {}
};

class Foo : public B1, public B2
{
};

template<class T, class U>
T implicit_cast(U p) { return p; }

int main()
{
    Foo* f = new Foo;
    void **ppv = new void*;

    *ppv = implicit_cast<B1*>(f);
    std::cout << *ppv << std::endl;;
    *ppv = implicit_cast<B2*>(f);
    std::cout << *ppv << std::endl;;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, `dynamic_cast` would be safer than `static_cast` but I didn't mention it because I've never seen it actually used (I heard about a performance hit but don't know how big it is).

Comment: @7vies: In Visual C++ it's about 2 thousand processor cycles and the compiler won't catch you if you cast your COM object to the wrong type - you'll only get a null pointer during runtime.

Comment: @sharptooth: Yep, `dynamic_cast` is definitely not the best option in the COM context. I'm not even sure in which situation it could be a good option at all - in most cases it can be replaced by run-time or compile-time polymorphism which would be safer and faster at the same time.