# How do i use this unique operator overloaded function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I came across this operator overload during my use of the sqlapi which does exactly what i need, but i'm not sure how it works.

sqlapi.h

```
class SQLAPI_API SAString
{
public:
//stuff

//! Return pointer to const string
operator const SAChar *() const;

//stuff
}
```

The only way that i know how to use it is because of the intellisense which doesn't look pretty:

```
char* chPointer = SAStringObj.operator const SAChar*();
```

**Questions:**

Is there a better looking way to call this overloaded operator?

Can someone dissect what this function header tells us about the function?

"*operator const SAChar *() const;*"

Comment: `SAString myString; const SAChar* chPointer = myString;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an implicit cast operator for converting an `SAString` to `const SAChar *`. It is implicitly invoked whenever you use an `SAString` in a context in which a `const SAChar *` is expected (unless it would be ambiguous).

```
void foo(const SAChar *);

SAString myString("bar");

foo(myString);
const SAChar *myCharPtr = myString;
```

You can use a `static_cast` to force it in other contexts:

```
static_cast<const SAChar *>(myString)
```

You can use `boost::implicit_cast` which is [safer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/868306/1639256):

```
boost::implicit_cast<const SAChar *>(myString)
```

In C++11 you can have an *explicit* cast operator which is only valid in explicit cast contexts:

```
explicit operator const SAChar *() const;
```

The `const` at the end has the usual meaning, just as for ordinary member functions.

Comment: Wow, that answer was perfect and answered all my questions. Also, is there any difference between a standard "(const SAChar*)myString" cast and a static_cast?